# IntelliJ IDEA. Make Git tab show unversioned files

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Is it possible to make IntelliJ Git tab show unversioned files the way VSCode GitGraph plugin does?

Thanks for advice.

[image: VSCode GitGraph plugin]
[image: Intellij Git tab]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With **Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Version Control | Commit | Use non-modal commit interface** enabled unversioned files are shown in the separate **Commit** tool window.

If you disable this option, unversioned files will appear in **Git** tool window under the **Local Changes** tab.

Comment: ah, i can't have it in the same "Log" tab as other commits. Ok, at least something :) thanks for hint